# str_replace do not work fo all the key

Tags: php, str-replace

I need to remove some chars from my string so I used the str_replace function as I always do but this doen't work.

I need to find the the string all the chars in the $array1 and replace them with the chars in $array2 in order to remove all the special chars that can cause trouble with my url.

Here my code:

```
$array1 = array('è','é','ò','à','ù','"','\'','ì',' ','.',',','<','>','&');
$array2 = array('e','e','o','a','u','','','i','-','','','','','');
$link = base_url().'esperto/tag/'.str_replace($array1,$array2,$val);
```

The problem is that this code just ignore some chars such as `à` for example.

If i set:

```
$val = "hello world";
```

the result is correct, I get:

```
hello-world
```

but if I use something like an italian word like:

```
$val = "aggressività";
```

in the $link I get the same value with no replace for the `à`.

The code should be correct, I cannot figure out what I'm missing here

Comment: It's almost certain that the text encoding of `$val` and the encoding of your source code file (i.e. that of the string literals such as `'à'`) are different. For example, one of them might be UTF-8 and the other might be single-byte. Or they could both be UTF-8 but not coherently normalized. You will have to find out which of the above is true.

Comment: This code works for me. Are you setting the correct headers? UTF-8 is advised as @Jon suggests. You can do so by setting a meta tag in the HTML page (<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">) and the correct header in the PHP page (header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');) Also make sure that any incoming content is UTF-8

Comment: Thanks Guys, it was an encoding issue! I spend about 30 minutes on this problem!!